# why i can't wrap methods from one dll but can do it for another?

Tags: dll, c++-cli

Im trying to write a wrapper in c++/cli for an DLL, which code i dont have, only DLL file and header but i created lib file through VS command prompt. When i`m trying to build solution i receive this errors:

```
DotNetWrappOfAsterSdkDll.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00002E) "void __stdcall MuteClearLastError(void)" (?MuteClearLastError@@$$FYGXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __clrcall DotNetWrappOfAsterSdkDll::WrapperClass2::doMuteClearLastError(void)" (?doMuteClearLastError@WrapperClass2@DotNetWrappOfAsterSdkDll@@$$FQ$AAMXXZ)
DotNetWrappOfAsterSdkDll.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall MuteClearLastError(void)" (?MuteClearLastError@@$$FYGXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __clrcall DotNetWrappOfAsterSdkDll::WrapperClass2::doMuteClearLastError(void)" (?doMuteClearLastError@WrapperClass2@DotNetWrappOfAsterSdkDll@@$$FQ$AAMXXZ)
```

I tried to create my own DLL and include it to the wrapper, and its working perfectly

here dll created by me which i can use in c++/cli wrapper:

```
//header file
#pragma once
#define DLLEXP   __declspec( dllexport )
namespace Computations {
    DLLEXP void someMethod(int number);
}

//cpp file
#include "Computations.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
//#include "pnl/pnl_random.h"

using namespace std;


void Computations::someMethod(int number)
{
    std::cout << "something "<<number*number << endl;
}
```

and here is part of header of DLL which i want to use:

```
#ifndef MUTEIFC_H
#define MUTEIFC_H

#include <Windows.h>

#ifdef MUTEIFC_LIBRARY
#  define MUTEAPI  extern "C"__declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define MUTEAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#define MUTECALL __stdcall

/** \ingroup init */
/** Initialization of the ASTER SDK library
  * \returns TRUE - success, FALSE - failure (use \ref MuteLastErrorCode or/and \ref MuteLastErrorInfo to get
  *                 failure cause)
  * \note This function will require Administrative privileges on the first call on a given computer.
  */
MUTEAPI BOOL MUTECALL MuteIfcInitialize(VOID);


/** \ingroup init */
/** Finialization of the ASTER SDK library
  */
MUTEAPI VOID MUTECALL MuteIfcFinalize(VOID);

/** \ingroup errors*/
/** Clears the calling thread's last-error code and description.
  * The last-error is maintained on a per-thread basis. Multiple threads do not overwrite each other's last-error.
  */
MUTEAPI VOID MUTECALL MuteClearLastError(VOID);
#endif // MUTEIFC_H
```

and my c++/cli code :

```
//header file
#pragma once
#include "Computations.h"
#include "muteifc.h"

using namespace System;

namespace DotNetWrappOfAsterSdkDll
{
    public ref class WrapperClass2
    {
        public:
        void doMuteClearLastError();
    };

    public ref class WrapperClass
    {
    private:
    public:
        void getPriceCallEuro(int number);

    };

}

//cpp file
#include "DotNetWrappOfAsterSdkDll.h"

using namespace DotNetWrappOfAsterSdkDll;

using namespace Computations;

namespace DotNetWrappOfAsterSdkDll
{
        //this dont work
    void WrapperClass2::doMuteClearLastError() {
        MuteClearLastError();
    }
        //this works great
    void WrapperClass::getPriceCallEuro(int number) {
        someMethod(number);
        //MuteIfcFinalize();
    }
}
```

Please tell me what i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't add the lib that contains the function reference to the linker options.

Either the lib contains he code it self or it has a reference to the DLL that must be loaded. The linker will bring your code and the DLL (or static lib) code together...